# Build Agent gets "Access Denied" when building modules in AX 7

Tags: azure-devops, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7, d3fo

I'm working on a Dynamics AX 7 Training VM. My boss asked me to write a documentation about the versioning in AX 7. I tested Git and now, I'm testing Visual Studio Online using Team Foundation as version controller.
So, I am able to set up a Build Agent with a Build Definition which will build my projects automatically.

BUT, it doesn't work of course ;)

I created a new model called "MyNewModel" and a project called Project2 associated with MyNewModel. But when I try to run a build, MyNewModel is detected and after that, its directory is "closed". I don't have any permissions anymore.

Oviously the build failed.

The only thing I can do is to delete that module via Source Control Explorer panel in Visual Studio and restart the VM to apply the changes ^^

I am desperate and lost so please, help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Thank you José Luis for your fast answer ! However i found the solution ^^
I didn't notice that Visual Studio was open all the time. I closed it and then I ran a Build and it worked.

Comment: How can i mark this topic as "Solved" ?

Comment: Edit your question to add the solution you found at the end.

Comment: @Rokkart Since your issue has been solved, you can post a new answer, then mark it after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by closing Visual Studio and then, I ran a Build and it worked, that's it.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why Visual Studio (the local application) was opened/involved in the first place. All builds should be started from the VSTS webapp and all errors that arise from the build should be troubleshot on a development environment. There aren't a lot of scenarios where you will have to actually access the build environment through RDP.

Comment: @int0xicated I know what you mean. As I said I was working on a Training VM hosted on our local servers. Due to a lack of resources, I had only 1 environment. This environment combined both dev and build environment. That's why VS was opened and I had to access it through RDP. Believe me I wish I had had 2 clean environments :(